# newdata argument in prediction function for natural spline and smoothing spline

Tags: r, prediction, splines

I am trying to plot a fitted spline with both ns() and smooth.spline() models. When I fit the spline I am unsure how I can set the newdata argument in the prediction function.

For the ns() model, it seems that I have to write the prediction function as `predict(fit, newdata= list(x= x.grid))` such that I can plot the fitted curve. If I leave out the `newdata` argument it will pop the error of x y differing in length.

For the smooth.spline() model, the prediction looks like this `predict(fit, x.grid)$y`. If I add the `newdata=`  argument it then returns me the `x y differing in length` error. Can someone explain why there is such a difference in the use of prediction function?

The code I am working on for natural spline model:

```
nob = 2
ncubic_ult = glm(mpg~ns(weight, df=2), data = Auto)
autote= Auto[te,]

testweightRange= range(autote$weight)
testweightgrid = seq( from=testweightRange[1], to=testweightRange[2], length.out=100 )
# prediction with list():
fittedmpg= predict(ncubic_ult, newdata = list(weight= testweightgrid))
plot( autote$weight, autote$mpg ,col='grey', main = 'newdata= list')
lines(testweightgrid, fittedmpg, col='red', lw=4)
```

Smoothing spline:

````
nob = 3
smooth_ult = smooth.spline(horsepower, mpg, df= nob)
autote= Auto[te,]
test_hpwRange= range(autote$horsepower)
test_hpwgrid = seq( from=test_hpwRange[1], to=test_hpwRange[2], length.out=100 )
fittedmpg= predict(smooth_ult,test_hpwgrid)$y
plot( autote$horsepower, autote$mpg ,col='grey', main = 'newdata= list')
lines(test_hpwgrid, fittedmpg, col='red', lw=4)

```
````

Comment: Hi, 

could you provide the data `Auto` with `dput(Auto)`?

Comment: The function `predict` is a generic and has some methods. 
Use `methods(predict)` in your console to figure out which methods exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `te` is, I have set it to `1:10`.

In the first case using `glm` the function `predict.glm` needs a data frame with a column named like the predictor variable.

In the second case the return of `predict.smooth.spline` is a list with `x` as input data (vector) and y as fitted values (also a vector)..meaning a list of vectors.

Here is my working example for you:

```r
library(splines)
library(ISLR) # for Auto datset: 

nob <- 2
ncubic_ult <- glm(mpg~ns(weight, df=2), data = Auto)

# don't now that te is... I set it to 1 to 10!
te <- 1:10
autote <- Auto[te,]

testweightRange <- range(autote$weight)
testweightgrid <- seq( from=testweightRange[1], to=testweightRange[2], length.out=100 )

# newdata; see ?predict.glm... it should be a data frame which to look for variables with which to predict!
new_data <- data.frame(weight = testweightgrid)

# prediction with newdata:
fittedmpg <- predict(ncubic_ult, newdata = new_data)
plot( autote$weight, autote$mpg ,col='grey', main = 'newdata= data.frame')
lines(testweightgrid, fittedmpg, col='red', lw=4)
```

[image]

```r
nob <- 3
smooth_ult <- smooth.spline(Auto$horsepower, Auto$mpg, df= nob)
autote <- Auto[te,]
test_hpwRange <- range(autote$horsepower)
test_hpwgrid <- seq( from=test_hpwRange[1], to=test_hpwRange[2], length.out=100 )

# see ?predict.smooth.spline. the output is a list with x as input data and y fitted values. 

fittedmpg <- predict(smooth_ult, x = test_hpwgrid)
plot( autote$horsepower, autote$mpg ,col='grey', main = 'newdata= vector')
lines(test_hpwgrid, fittedmpg$y, col='red', lw=4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh I was not aware of the R documentation of the specific prediction functions for individual models. If the description mentions argument 'x', then is it referring to a vector/ sequence?

Comment: In R it is often the case that `x` refers to a vector. In good docs like `?t.test` it is explicitly said that x refers to ' a (non-empty) numeric vector of data values.'